# Managing storage for Virtual Machines in Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization (RHEV)

Tags: virtualization, redhat

I am using RHEV and I have created two virtual machines. These have too little disk space, how can I edit the disk space of these machines? I cannot find the option anywhere.

Comment: This belongs on serverfault

Answer (score 0):

You can create new volumes of desired capacity and simply attach them to VM through RHEV Manager WebUI.